# Segmentation Fault on String Creation

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

I've been developing a program to read a data from a file, then I received a Seg Fault when I tried to create a constant size string.

```
FILE *in = fopen("entrada.txt", "r");

t_mapa *mapa;
t_jogador *jogadores;
jogadores = NULL;

int i, num_jogadores, tamanho_mapa;
char *token1, *token2;
char str1[4], str2[4]; //RIGHT HERE WHEN I CREATE THE STRING, I RECEIVE A SEG FAULT

if(in == NULL){
    printf("Arquivo Não pode ser aberto");
}


fscanf(in, "%d", &tamanho_mapa);
printf("%d\n", tamanho_mapa); //Debugger
mapa->mapa = cria_mapa(tamanho_mapa);
preenche_mapa(mapa, in, tamanho_mapa);
fscanf(in, "%d", &num_jogadores);
printf("%d %p\n", num_jogadores, jogadores); //Debugger
jogadores = cria_jogadores(num_jogadores);


for(i=0; i<num_jogadores; i++){
    fscanf(in, "%s %s", str1, str2);
    token1 = strtok(str2, ",");
    token2 = strtok(NULL, ",");
    jogadores[i].linha = atoi(token1);
    jogadores[i].coluna = atoi(token2);
}
```

Comment: How do you know that is where the crash is? Because that is code that can't lead to crashes unless you have a stack overflow (and that would not manifest as a segmentation fault). Please use a debugger to catch the crash in action, and find out where in your code it *really* happens.

Comment: I have two guesses about the error though: Either one of the `strtok` Calls return a `NULL` pointer (which you do not check for). Or you forget that strings in C need an extra character for the terminating `'\0'`, and you write out of bounds of your arrays. A third reason might be that `cria_jogadores` fails to allocate memory, or returns a pointer to alocal array.

Comment: `char str1[4], str2[4];` look pathetically small to read from a file strings that contain two tokens. That would mean input in the form of 3-char strings such as `"a,b"`

Comment: If the segfault happens where you commented, the damage previously happened at some other place in the program.

Comment: Please show a complete and minimal example that demonstrates your problem. By "complete" I mean that you should show the whole `main.c` file. By "minimal" I mean that you should remove everything that doesn't contribute to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

So I have a different theory, I think the next line is the culprit

```
mapa->mapa = cria_mapa(tamanho_mapa);
```

That is only if like in the code given here, you defined `mapa` like this

```
t_mapa *mapa;
```

You don't seem to initialise it to anything, but then dereference it using the `->` operator.

Other than this I don't see anything wrong directly. We would need more of the code to give a better answer.